# Missing guid when deserializing object using JSON and C#

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, missing-data

I'm using newtonsoft's library to deserialize a slightly complex object and have hit a snag where the Ids within the MetaData object aren't being populated, every other value appears to be fine. All the main objects are derived from the model
class which has the core properties such as the Id. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what's going wrong here?

This is the JSON I'm using to test, the top level object is a page:

```
{
  "CreatedOn": "2012-07-30T13:42:45+01:00",
  "CreatedBy": "33576D49-B799-4326-812C-D6A3C47B7035",
  "Name": "Icecream",
  "Metadata": [
    {
      "CreatedOn": "2012-07-30T14:06:31+01:00",
      "ModifiedOn": "2012-07-30T14:06:31+01:00",
      "ModifiedBy": "53D947AC-0D7B-42C4-929E-DAFC25932784",
      "Name": "Colour",
      "Value": "Blue",
      "NodeReference": "834a2734-e807-4eb7-a242-c26d785681f3",
      "Scope": "Draft",
      "Id": "032488bd-158c-4064-93ec-44bd11c4e642",
      "CreatedBy": "53D947AC-0D7B-42C4-929E-DAFC25932784"
    },
    {
      "CreatedOn": "2012-07-30T13:48:49+01:00",
      "ModifiedOn": "2012-07-30T14:23:20+01:00",
      "ModifiedBy": "10E0821E-1982-4C24-B9E1-35FAF9A547BB",
      "Name": "Topping",
      "Value": "Chocolate sprinkles",
      "NodeReference": "834a2734-e807-4eb7-a242-c26d785681f3",
      "Scope": "Live",
      "Id": "241afb40-0d83-4599-a05e-aec1a6cdef41",
      "CreatedBy": "CE1F79DE-9ECF-456F-8C17-D9B7E4B6FCA7"
    }
  ],
  "WikiResources": [    
  ],
  "FileResources": [    
  ],
  "Links": [    
  ],
  "Id": "834a2734-e807-4eb7-a242-c26d785681f3"
}
```

Here is a (simplified) version of my code:

```
public abstract class Model {

    protected Guid? _id;
    public Guid? Id {
        get {  return _id;}
        set { _id = value; IsDirty = true; }
    }

    private string _name; //e.g page Heading
    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; IsDirty = true; }
    }

    private DateTime _createdOn;
    public DateTime CreatedOn {
        get { return _createdOn; }
        set { _createdOn = value; IsDirty = true; }
    }

    private string _createdBy;
    public string CreatedBy {
        get { return _createdBy; }
        set { _createdBy = value; IsDirty = true; }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsDirty {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsNew {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private List<MetaDatum> _metadata;
    public List<MetaDatum> MetaData {
        get {
            return _metadata;
        }
        set {
            _metadata = value;
        }
    }
}



public class MetaDatum : Model, IModel {

    //other properties and methods omitted

    #region construction

        public MetaDatum() {
            IsNew = false;
            webservice = WebserviceManager.GetWebservice();

        }

        //quick factory method for creating a name value pair
        public static MetaDatum Create(string name, string value, ScopeType scope) {
            MetaDatum md = new MetaDatum();
            md.Name = name;         
            md.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            md.Scope = scope;
            md.Value = value.ToString();
            md.IsNew = true;
            md.IsDirty = true;
            return md;
        }

        #endregion

}

public class Page : Model, IModel {

    //other properties and methods omitted

    public static Page Deserialize(string text) {

            if (text == "" || text == null)
                return null;

            dynamic serializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
            Page convertedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Page>(text);

            return convertedObject;
        }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around to fetch the Ids manually after deserialization, by setting it as a dynamic object and drilling into it. But perhaps there's a better way to do this in one go?

```
int i = 0;           
dynamic serializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
foreach (dynamic item in serializedObj.Metadata) {
    convertedObject.MetaData[i++].Id = Guid.Parse(item.Id.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate the type of data you are sending in the header I mean `MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue` ("`text / plain`") <- since it can be an application / Json or text / json, this type can be changed serialization can be done